# Android: ClassCastException on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom ListView with a TextView and Checkbox(with button image), when clicked on textview a hidden layout expands for that particular row and when clicked on checkbox that particular row is selected for deletion. And I'm getting this `ClasCcastException` when I tag the view to `ViewHolder` class object `holder` for CheckBox's `OnCheckedChangeListener`.
Here is my code,

**CustomListView.class**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = null;
    DataFields rowItems = (DataFields) getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_field_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.dataFields = items.get(position);
        holder.mName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldName);
        holder.mDeleteCheck = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.deleteCheck);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mDeleteCheck.setTag(position);
    holder.mName.setTag(position);

    holder.mName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                holder = (ViewHolder) ((View) v.getParent()).getTag(); //Works fine here
                ...
        }
    });

    holder.mDeleteCheck
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                    holder = (ViewHolder) ((View) buttonView.getParent()).getTag(); //throwing ClassCastException
                    ...
                }
            });

    holder.mName.setText(rowItems.getName());
    holder.mDeleteCheck.setChecked(deletePositions[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

I hope my question is clear. Any kind of help or suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks !

**Edit**

Logcat -

```
03-09 12:08:45.789: E/AndroidRuntime(3661): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 12:08:45.789: E/AndroidRuntime(3661): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
03-09 12:08:45.789: E/AndroidRuntime(3661):     at com.inkers.forgetpassword.utility.CustomListArrayAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(CustomListArrayAdapter.java:173)
03-09 12:08:45.789: E/AndroidRuntime(3661):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:124)
03-09 12:08:45.789: E/AndroidRuntime(3661):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
03-09 12:08:45.789: E/AndroidRuntime(3661):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @Luksprog I posted my logcat, please check it.

Comment: Please post the custom layout for the listview items that you are using.

Comment: would be glad to see this custom lazyout too  plz post home_field_row.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your layout xml file,  I can only guess but it seems that your checkbox is not a direct child of your root view (the row viewgroup) as your TextView is.

so first : check this hierarchy : is there another ViewGroup between the checkbox and the root viewgroup ? ( the one that's pointed by checkbox.getParent and cause the classcastException)

second : you should consider simplifying this code, it seems a little bit complicated for what you try to achieve...

third : show the lawout xml file if you want better answers ;)

Comment: Thanks ! You are right. CheckBox is not a direct child of the root layout. Its fixed :)

Comment: you're walcom, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

What is a buttonView and why do you think its parent has a tag which is instance of ViewHolder? The second point is - use ViewHolder holder = null. This will prevent using wrong holder in OnClickListeners.

Answer (score 0):

parent of buttonview does not contain tag of view holder. tag is contain in list item. you will get tag on item click listener.

You can use setVisibility(View.GONE) of your view that you want to display on click of check box.

for parent of button view you can get that view which you use for visibility on/off.